# Hard drive is listed in lsblk but does not show in fdisk or gparted, drive showing no SMART errors

Tags: gparted

I am trying to wipe a HDD that was subject to a ransomware attack.  I have plugged it in to a different machine using a SATA to USB adapter but it does not show up in gparted.

If I run `lsblk`, the drive is listed under /dev/sdb but with no partitions:

```
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
```

When I run `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` I get an error saying

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

If I run smartctl -a /dev/sdb I get the following:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.8.6-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST2000DM001-1CH164
Serial Number:    Z3404K75
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 04e94366b
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Sep 28 20:47:24 2020 BST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  575) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 218) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   117   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       120025296
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   092   091   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   096   096   020    Old_age   Always       -       4667
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       16
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   055   049   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       111679067288
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   044   044   000    Old_age   Always       -       49523
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       109
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   068   039   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 32 (0 120 32 23 0)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       60
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       4667
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   061   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (0 11 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2112h+46m+24.124s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       13129501480
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       13098662457

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     49522         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

which seems to say the test passed with no errors, so I am unsure as to why I cannot get the drive to show up in gparted?

EDIT: I am able to use SATA to USB adapter with another HDD and can view data on that fine, so I know the adapter is working correctly

EDIT 2: Output from dmesg

```
[ 2981.448847] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2981.452532] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 2982.460121] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Book 1110     2003 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2982.460836] scsi 3:0:0:1: CD-ROM            WD       Virtual CD 1110  2003 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2982.465122] scsi 3:0:0:2: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       2003 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2982.473198] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 3905656832 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.82 TiB)
[ 2982.475177] sr 3:0:0:1: [sr1] scsi3-mmc drive: 51x/51x caddy
[ 2982.478064] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2982.478071] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 10 00
[ 2982.479624] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 2982.479631] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2982.491066] sr 3:0:0:1: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 2982.491576] ses 3:0:0:2: Attached Enclosure device
[ 2982.503215] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2982.503225] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2982.503233] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2982.503239] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2982.503247] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2982.503255] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2982.504381] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2982.504390] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2982.504398] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2982.504405] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2982.504411] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2982.504418] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2982.504462] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 2982.505904] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2982.505912] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2982.505920] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2982.505926] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2982.505932] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2982.505939] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2982.506698] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2982.506706] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2982.506716] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2982.506722] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2982.506729] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2982.506736] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2982.509562] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2982.509568] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2982.509574] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2982.509579] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2982.509584] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2982.509590] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2982.509614]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 2982.513827] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2982.543747] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2982.543754] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2982.543759] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2982.543764] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 cb 97 80 00 00 08 00
[ 2982.543770] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 3905656704 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2982.545043] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[ 2982.545050] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2982.545059] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2982.545064] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 cb 97 80 00 00 08 00
[ 2982.545072] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 3905656704 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2982.545078] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 488207088, async page read
```

Is this drive salvageable?

EDIT 3: Output of `hdparm -Ii /dev/sdb`

```
/dev/sdb:
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       ST2000DM001-1CH164                      
    Serial Number:      Z3404K75
    Firmware Revision:  CC43    
    Transport:          Serial, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0029) 
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  3907029168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 3.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: 7200
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = ?
    Advanced power management level: 128
    Recommended acoustic management value: 208, current value: 0
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 *mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT Write Same (AC2)
            unknown 206[7]
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    210min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 210min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000c5004e94366b
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : 000c50
    Unique ID   : 04e94366b
Checksum: correct
```

Comment: dmesg for I/O error? there are reallocated sectors so the drive already has a history. plus it was only a short test...

Comment: @frostschutz, updated question with output from dmesg, is this drive salvageable?

Comment: @frostschutz:  Even an extended test may fail to find extremely obvious problems.

Comment: Some adapters and some SATA drives do not cooperate. This particular drive might work via another adapter, or if connected directly to a SATA port in a computer.

Comment: this seems like your drive is locked with a password?

Comment: @frostschutz, could this be due to the ransomware? Is there anything I can do to just wipe it and start from fresh?

Comment: probably can't help you there... `hdparm -Ii`?

Comment: @frostschutz: Updated question with output

Comment: Have you tried yet to wipe the drive with some tool? -- For example `hdparm` or DBAN? It is safer and maybe easier too, if you connect the drive directly to a SATA port, or if available via eSATA, particularly if you use hdparm, because there are warnings to wipe with `hdparm` via USB.

Comment: Put it in my unraid machine and formatted it on there, seems to be working fine now

Comment: I knew SSD should often have firmware updates. Your HDD also has a firmware update available. https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/barracuda-1tbdisk-platform-firmware-update-223651en/

Comment: Please run `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdb` and then post `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` output. Most likely your drive is failing.